# Why does the message str object Has no attribute id appear?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am Korean and I would appreciate it if you could understand my poor English.

Question:

I am making a bot at discord. 
It seems that the user did not enter the value in id when transferring the user to voice channel through bot. 
Is for a function not applied?
I really appreciate your reply with a simple example that is easy to understand.

```
lst = []
async def on_message(message):


    if message.content.startswith('>커맨드'):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="커맨드 목록", description='\n\nHeimish클랜 팀봇 입니다. \n\n >추가 ○○ : 멤버를 추가합니다. \n\n >제외 ○○ : 멤버를 제외합니다. \n\n >초기화 : 추가되어있는 모든 멤버를 삭제합니다. \n\n >팀2 : 2명 정원의 팀을 구성합니다. \n\n >팀3 : 3명 정원의 팀을 구성합니다. \n\n >팀4 : 4명 정원의 팀을 구성합니다. \n\n >팀5 : 5명 정원의 팀을 구성합니다.\n\n', color=0x00ff00)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)

    elif message.content.startswith('>추가'):
        x = message.content.split()
        if(len(x) ==2):
            tmp= x[len(x)-1]
            j=0 
            for i in range(0,len(lst)):
                if(tmp == lst[i]) == True:  
                    j=j+1
            if j == 0:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="신청", description="%s님이 추가되었습니다!."% tmp, color=0x00ff00)
                await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
                lst.append(tmp) 
            else: 
                embed = discord.Embed(title="띠용", description="%s님 중복지원입니다!."% tmp, color=0x00ff00)
                await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="띠용", description="명령어에 맞게 다시 입력하세요!", color=0x00ff00)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
    elif message.content.startswith('>보이스'):
        if(message.author.display_name != '김진혁'):
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Access failed", description='only access person', color=0x00ff00)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed)
        else:
            person = '김진혁'
            channel = discord.utils.find(lambda x: x.name == 'squad-1', message.server.channels)
            #for i in range(0,len(lst)):
            await client.move_member(person , channel)
```

Comment: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/heimish.py", line 185, in on_message
    await client.move_member('김진혁' , channel)

Comment: File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 3135, in move_member
    yield from self.http.move_member(member.id, member.server.id, channel.id)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: it's my full error code.

Comment: Put it in the question so you can format it readably.

Comment: The first argument to `client.move_member()` is supposed to be a `Member` object, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `client.move_member()` must be a `Member`, but you're passing a string. Use:

```
person = message.author
```